# Richfaces 4, missing HtmlCalendar, HtmlColumn, HtmlComboBox, HtmlComponentControl, HtmlSpacer, HtmlToolTip

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, components

I'm just checking if my application can be migrated from 3.3.1 to 4.3.7, going from JSF 1.2 to 2.1 the same time.

The JSF upgrade gave me some troubles which i could resolve. But now i'm clueless.

I've included the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
  <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, one of my classes assembles a page using the HTML-components. The import shows:

```
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlCalendar;
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlColumn;
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlComboBox;
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlComponentControl;
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlSpacer;
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlToolTip;
```

These imports no longer can be resolved. I've searches the jar. There **is** a folder "richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final\org\richfaces\component\html", but none of the classes is included.

I know there is a rich:calendar, but where is the corresponding component-class?

Am i missing a dependency?

Thanks
Holger

Answer (score 0):

Most of these (if not all) can be found by replacing:

```
org.richfaces.component.html.Html*
```

with

```
org.richfaces.component.UI*
```

i.e. drop the `.html.` package part and replace `Html` prefix with `UI`. e.g.

```
org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable
```

is now

```
org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable
```

The classes aren't fully compatible but at least most of it is (still) there. Hope this helps.